# Get the dropdown element to work - Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to select "L4 Segmentation" from the Category dropdown menu

[image: Category]

```html
<div data-fragment-id="auditable-entity-form">
  <form data-behavior="fragments" class=" new_auditable_entity warns-when-has-unsaved-data " id="new_auditable_entity" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/auditable_entities" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>New Entity</legend>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label for="auditable_entity_title">
          Name
          <span class="help-tip"> (120 characters max)</span>
        </label>
        <input class="span6" maxlength="120" size="120" type="text" name="auditable_entity[title]" id="auditable_entity_title">
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label for="auditable_entity_entity_type_id">Category <span class="help-tip">(optional)</span></label>

        <div class="controls">
          <select class="acts-as-singleselect" data-placeholder="Select Category" data-width="200px" name="auditable_entity[entity_type_id]" id="auditable_entity_entity_type_id" style="display: none;">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="5230">Enterprise Applications</option>
            <option value="5229">LMTS Applications</option>
            <option value="5221">LCHC Applications</option>
            <option value="5366">L1  Segmentation</option>
            <option value="5367">L2 Segmentation</option>
            <option value="5368">L3 Segmentation</option>
            <option value="5369">L4 Segmentation</option>
          </select>
          <div class="singleselect-container is-active" id="auditable_entity_entity_type_id_singleselect" style="width: 200px;">
            <div class="singleselect-toggle">
              <span class="singleselect-value">Select Category</span>
              <span class="acl-throbber tiny"></span>
            </div>


            <div class="singleselect-drop">
              <div class="singleselect-search">
                <input type="text" class="singleselect-filter" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              </div>


              <ul class="singleselect-list">
      
                <li data-value="" class="singleselect-item is-selected">
                      None
                </li>

                <li data-value="5230" class="singleselect-item">
                      Enterprise Applications
                </li>

                <li data-value="5229" class="singleselect-item">
                      LMTS Applications
                </li>

                <li data-value="5221" class="singleselect-item">
                      LCHC Applications
                </li>

                <li data-value="5366" class="singleselect-item">
                      L1 Segmentation
                </li>

                <li data-value="5367" class="singleselect-item">
                      L2 Segmentation
                </li>

                <li data-value="5368" class="singleselect-item">
                      L3 Segmentation
                </li>

                <li data-value="5369" class="singleselect-item">
                      L4 Segmentation
                </li>


              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Method 1: I've tried Select

```
catElem = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('auditable_entity_entity_type_id'))
```

```
catElem.select_by_visible_text('L4 Segmentation')
```

I've tried adding wait time as well

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'auditable_entity_entity_type_id')))
```

I get that common error saying "element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated".

Method 2: I noticed that the element right below the `<select>` element is actually clickable, I've managed to click the dropdown by doing this:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('auditable_entity_entity_type_id_singleselect').click()
```

How do I get Select to work (Method 1), or how to do I select the option once I have the dropdown open (Method 2)?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is actually a pretty good description of what is happening.

> element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

From the HTML snippet you posted:

```html
<select class="..." data-placeholder="..." data-width="..." name="..." id="auditable_entity_entity_type_id" style="display: none;">
```

Notice the attribute `style="display: none;"`. This causes the element to not be rendered, and since Selenium acts as a user would and attempts to click on the element with the mouse, the attempt fails since you cannot click on something that is not displayed.

The workaround for this depends entirely on the way the site has been built and how they implement (or ignore) best practices regarding semantic HTML. The best way to find out how to program the interaction in Selenium would be to perform the steps you want manually and use the development tools of your browser to see which elements you are actually clicking on. Many websites re-implement common controls such as `<select>` elements with custom styled lists using JavaScript and event handlers, so the elements you should be selecting may not be the ones you would expect simply by viewing the page's source code.

For the second method you tried, perhaps try clicking on the `<li>` element with the "L4 Segmentation" text after you open the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
<select class="acts-as-singleselect" data-placeholder="Select Category" 
data-width="200px" name="auditable_entity[entity_type_id]" 
id="auditable_entity_entity_type_id" style="display: none;">
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As per [CSS Layout - The display Property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

> `display: none;` is commonly used with JavaScript to hide and show elements without deleting and recreating them.

Therefore you will not be able to use [Select](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) class as elements which are not visible are not clickable, the correct way of interacting with the dropdown would be something like:

```
cat_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Search']")))
cat_elem.click()

l4_segmentation = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(),'L4 Segmentation']")))
l4_segmentation.click()
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Comment: I have tried this as well, but i got the time out error. I will dig into the link you provided, i feel like i've exhausted every method i can think of :(